# Call the properties/methods on the Piped Object

Tags: powershell

I am trying to understand how to `pipe |` an object and call the properties or methods on that.

```
Ex:
$a = Get-Item Registry::HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Test\abc\
$a.GetSomething()  //calls the method
(Get-Item Registry::HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Test\abc\).GetSomething() //calls the method
```

Can I pipe the output of the `Get-Item` and `invoke properties/methods` on it?

```
Get-Item Registry::HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Test\abc\ | call GetSomething()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is **no**. You can't call a method like this using Pipeline. But you can surround your `Get-Item` invoke in parentheses and invoke it:

```
(Get-Item Registry::HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Test\abc\).GetSomething()
```

---

If you don't want that, you could abuse the `Select-Object` cmdlet:

```
Get-Item Registry::HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Test\abc\  | select { $_.GetSomething() }
```

Comment: That's sad. Imagine I am not sure about `Reg key` or the `Folder` exists or not. I just keep go on using `tab` so that I get to place where I want using `auto-suggestion` and to call something now, all of sudden I have to wrap it from the start can call a method. It's really pain

Comment: The canonical way would be `ForEach-Object`. It can be written pretty concise using the alias `%`: `... | % { $_.method() }`

Comment: @martin-brandl , your short answer seems to be absolutely wrong. Please look into `ForEach-Object` documentation.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible without writing something to make it so. That something would be pretty confusing.

Like this.

```
filter Invoke-Method {
    param(
        [String]$Method,

        [Object[]]$ArgumentList
    )

    $_.GetType().InvokeMember(
        $Method.Trim(),
        ([System.Reflection.BindingFlags]'InvokeMethod'),
        $null,
        $_,
        $ArgumentList
   )
}
"qwerty" | Invoke-Method Replace 'q', 'z'
```

Properties are easier in that there's already a command to do that:

```
(...).GetSomething() | Select-Object Property1, Property2
```

Comment: would be also good to have such filter for calling static method such as

` [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString `

to make possible something like:

` Invoke-WebRequest $url | select Content | 
 Invoke-Static System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString `

trying to construct... or asking as separate question

Answer (score 1):

A nicer method in my opinion would be to use e.g.:

`Get-Item Registry::HKLM | % { $_ }`:

where `%` is `ForEach-Object` (which is fine to use, even if you only have 1) and `$_` is each object.

Answer (score 0):

[Ansgar Wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers) has provided the crucial pointer in a comment on [Martin Brandl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39034632/45375):

> The canonical way would be **`ForEach-Object`**. It can be written pretty concisely using the alias `%`: 
> `... | % { $_.GetSomething() }`

In PowerShell version 3 or higher, you an **make the call even more concise with [*simplified syntax*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Simplified_Syntax)**, which obviates the need for enclosing the call in `{ ... }`, having to explicitly refer to `$_`, and needing to use parentheses (`(...)`):

```bash
... | % GetSomething  # short for: ... | ForEach-Object GetSomething
```

Note that if the method takes arguments, they must be supplied as an *array* (`,`-separated), but *without enclosing them in `(...)`*, because syntactically the arguments are being passed in [*argument mode*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing), which also makes quoting simple string values optional - see examples below.

**Examples**:

Method call *without arguments*:

```bash
# Perform the equivalent of:
# (Get-Item Registry::HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\txtfile).GetValueNames()     
# That is, get the names of the values defined on registry key 
# HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\txtfile
PS> Get-Item Registry::HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\txtfile | % GetValueNames

EditFlags
FriendlyTypeName
```

Method call with *one* argument:

```bash
# Perform the equivalent of (Get-Date).ToString('u'); i.e.,
# get a date's universally sortable string representation.
PS> Get-Date | % ToString u  # "u" may be quoted, but doesn't need to be.
2019-04-19 08:22:22Z
```

Method call with *multiple arguments*:

```bash
# Perform the equivalent of 'foo'.Replace('f', 'F'); i.e.,
# replace all lowercase Fs with uppercase ones.
PS> 'foo' | % Replace f F
Foo
```

Answer (score 0):

This requirement in most cases says that the task can be accomplished in a simpler way.

However, if it is really needed, you can use the `MemberName` parameter of the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet:

```bsh
# declare something
$o = @{
    One   = 1
    Two   = 2
    Three = 6
}

# do something
$o |
    ForEach-Object -MemberName "GetEnumerator" |
    ForEach-Object { "$($_.Key): $($_.Value)" } |
    Write-Host
```