# Call methods on the Piped Object

Tags: powershell, methods, pipeline

It would be good to have a PS filter for calling method such as

`[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString`

to make possible something like:

```
filter Invoke-Method { ... ?? ... }

Invoke-WebRequest $url `
    | Select-Object Content `
    | Invoke-Method [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39034294/call-the-properties-methods-on-the-piped-object) is a sample for member call, but my attempts to construct something like this for my case failed by the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Provided the input object is typed correctly, yes:

```
filter Invoke-Method {
  param(
    [System.Management.Automation.PSMethod]
    $Method
  )

  return $Method.Invoke($_)
}

(65..74 -as [byte[]]) |Invoke-Method -Method ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString)
```

Comment: An elegant solution that works well in the OP's scenario and is even faster than `... | % { [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($_) }`; however, it's generally only an option with a _static_ method (at least with reasonable performance).
As an aside: I suggest passing the byte array _as a whole_ to the method; UTF8-decoding bytes _individually_ is pointless (except for code points in the ASCII range).

Answer (score 0):

[Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55760590/45375) shows an elegant solution to your question as asked.

However, the **approach is limited to passing a *static* method** to which to pass the pipeline object at hand, whereas **PowerShell does have a *built-in* flexible per-pipeline-input processing command**: the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) cmdlet, whose built-in alias is `%`, to which you pass a script block (`{ ... }`) inside of which `$_` refers to the pipeline input object at hand):

```
PS> , [byte[]] (0x68, 0xc3, 0xaf) | % { [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($_) }
hï
```

Note that in order to convert a byte array representing UTF8-encoded text back to a string, you must send it *as a whole* through the pipeline, which is what the unary array-construction operator `,` achieves here (it wraps the byte array in a helper array, which, on enumeration in the pipeline, sends the byte array as a whole).

Things become even easier syntactically if the method to **invoke** is **a member of each pipeline input object**, in which case you can **use an *operation statement*** (PSv3+):

```
# Call the .ToUpper() method on each input string:
PS> 'foo', 'bar' | % ToUpper # short for: 'foo', 'bar' | % { $_.ToUpper() }
FOO
BAR
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55761925/45375) for details.

---

**Performance considerations**:

<sup>Written as of PowerShell Core 6.2.0.</sup>

Surprisingly, **an operation statement - despite not involving a script block - is *slower* than the equivalent script-block syntax**;
e.g., `'foo', 'bar' | % ToUpper` is slower than `'foo', 'bar' | % { $_.ToUpper() }`

Defining **a filter function is fastest by far**, but, as stated, limited to static methods (the speed advantage would turn into the opposite if you passed the operation to perform via a *script block* or by member *name* using *reflection* via `.psobject.Methods`).

However, **if performance is paramount** and you do need to call a method on each input object, you could define a filter function with  a *hard-coded* method call:

```
filter ToUpper { $_.ToUpper() }
'foo', 'bar' | ToUpper  # much faster than: 'foo', 'bar' | % ToUpper
```